# form with multiple select boxes doesn't work properly in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Could someone explain me why my form doesn't work properly:

```
 <%= form_for current_user, url: change_my_team_path, method: :put, remote: true, id: "my-team-form" do |f| %>

                  <div class="countries" id="england">
                      <%= f.select :team, options_for_select(select_apl_teams), {:include_blank => change_blank(current_user)}, {:onchange=>"$(this.form).submit();", class: "selectpicker", "data-live-search"=>"true"} %>
                  </div> 
                  <div class="countries" id="spain">
                      <%= f.select :team, options_for_select(select_laliga_teams), {:include_blank => change_blank(current_user)}, {:onchange=>"$(this.form).submit();", class: "selectpicker", "data-live-search"=>"true"} %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="countries" id="italy">
                      <%= f.select :team, options_for_select(select_seria_teams), {:include_blank => change_blank(current_user)}, {:onchange=>"$(this.form).submit();", class: "selectpicker", "data-live-search"=>"true"} %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="countries" id="germany">
                      <%= f.select :team, options_for_select(select_bundesliga_teams), {:include_blank => change_blank(current_user)}, {:onchange=>"$(this.form).submit();", class: "selectpicker", "data-live-search"=>"true"} %>
                  </div>

 <% end %>
```

This form is working only when I use last select box, first 3 not working.  When I change the order I have the same behavior, the last select box is working, first three aren't working.

I have some reason to use 4 select boxes in one form. if someone has any thoughts I'll be appreciated.

Comment: You are using same name for all select boxes hence last one overrides all other selections. use different names like `f.select :team_spain` , `f.select :team_england`  and have columns with same name in database. Then your form will work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

`f.select :team` will generate select boxes with same name and id so first it violets HTML rule of unique id for every node then again since it has same name and rails get params from elements name, it picks up the value from the last element.

Answer (score 0):

yep, it doesn't work because you redefine attributes each time when you add new `select`, you have to use one select box with `multiple` attribute:

```
f.select :team, options_for_select(select_laliga_teams), multiple: true
```

and in this case you will be able to choose multiple values with pushed `ctrl` button

Comment: Hi Oleg. Thanks for your answer. I came up with another solution. I created hidden field f.hidden_field :team, and via JS I pass value from my select boxes, then call $(this.form).submit();",. I am not sure that it is the best solution, but it works exactly as I need.

Comment: maybe will be more simple to use `check_box`?

Comment: I have a bit nervous designer, don't want to upset him:)